# Can R download specific files from a list of webpages?

Tags: r, download

I have a files would like to download from a webpage, e.g.

http://www.pdb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=2FBA
http://www.pdb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=2GVS

I have a list contains 2FBA, 2GVS, etc....

By using RCurl and XML, I know R can help to scrap information from a website to a dataframe.  Can I use R to download all the 2FBA.pdb, 2GVS.pdb, etc files from the webpages, while using R to instruct how to replace the last 4 letters (2FBA to 2GVS...) and download all these files to my working computer?

It seems to me that it can be done by python (previous reply from the stackoverflow).  However, I am not very familiar with python.  That's why I am asking if R can do similar things for me in a smart way.  Thanks for comments.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one approach using the `plyr` package. The idea is to construct a function that downloads the pdb file for a given protein, and then using `l_ply` in `plyr` to loop through a list of proteins.

```
# function to download pdb file for a given protein
download_pdb = function(protein){

    base_url  = "http://www.pdb.org/pdb/files/"
    dest_file = paste(protein, '.pdb.gz', sep = "")    
    protein_url = paste(base_url, dest_file, sep = "")
    download.file(protein_url, destfile = dest_file)

}

proteins  = list('2FBA', '2GVS')
require(plyr)
l_ply(proteins, download_pdb)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would first paste together the desired url and use `download.file` from the `utils` package.
Something along the lines of

```
my.url <- "www.somewhere.com"
my.files <- c("file1.xxx", "file2.xxx", "file3.xxx")

my.list <- as.list(paste(my.url, my.files, sep = "/"))

my.dl <- lapply(X = my.list, FUN = download.file)
```